# Logitech m280 nano wireless mouse

Tags: mouse, logitech

I need to ask you about wireless mouse logitech  m 280 that the scroll middle button not function properly.

Comment: Have you been able to test it on another computer/ OS to make sure it physically works?

Comment: yes.windows 7 it works.